# QLineEdit has no object attribute 'clicked' in PyQt5?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, qt-designer

In PyQt5 i want you add a functionality where when i clicked QLineEdit box, push button got yellow which is previously white. and when clicked 'SET' button it got black again.

but the problem is QEditLine has no clicked functionality.

When i run this below code it gives the error **QLineEdit has no object attribute 'clicked'**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
import sys

class mylineedit(QLineEdit):
  clicked=pyqtSignal()  # Definition clicked Signal
  def mouseReleaseEvent(self, QMouseEvent):
    if QMouseEvent.button()==Qt.LeftButton:
      self.clicked.emit()

class MainWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle("Hatchery System")
        self.resize(1064, 665)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: white")
        self.setFixedWidth(700)
        self.setFixedHeight(500)

        self.button_5 = QPushButton('', self)
        self.button_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(350, 50, 61, 71))
        self.button_5.setStyleSheet("background-color: red;")
        self.button_5.setIcon(QIcon('/home/lenovo/PycharmProjects/test/images/bulb_black.svg'))
        self.button_5.setCheckable(True)
        self.button_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))
        self.button_5.clicked.connect(self.button_bulb_clicked)

        self.line = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self)
        self.line.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(200, 150, 260, 161))
        self.line.setStyleSheet("color: rgb(239, 41, 41);" "Font: Italic;")
        self.line.setText("33.3")
        self.line.setFont(QFont("Ani", 100))
        self.line.clicked.connect(self.button_bulb_clicked)
        # self.clicked.connect(self.button_bulb_clicked())

        self.button = QPushButton('', self)
        self.button.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(500, 230, 61, 71))
        self.button.setText("SET")
        self.button.setCheckable(True)
        self.button.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))

    def button_bulb_clicked(self):
        if self.line.isChecked():
            self.button_5.setIcon(QIcon('/home/lenovo/PycharmProjects/test/images/bulb_yellow.svg'))
        else:
            self.button_5.setIcon(QIcon('/home/lenovo/PycharmProjects/test/images/bulb_black.svg'))
            self.button_5.setIconSize(QtCore.QSize(32, 32))

app = QApplication([])
mw = MainWindow()
mw.show()
app.exec_()
```

OutPut:
[image]

Comment: you can use this code "self.lineedit.mousePressEvent = self.click" then you can set self.click function

Comment: @SimoNSavioR can you please elaborate it?

Comment: You've created the subclass, but you're not using it. Change to `self.line = mylineedit()`. You should also call the base implementation of the mouse press, and use a proper name for the argument (QMouseEvent is a class, overwriting the name even at function level is wrong): change to `def mousePressEvent(self, event):` and add `super().mousePressEvent(event)` at the base indentation level of the function. Note that class names should be capitalized, so you should name it with something like "MyLineEdit".

Comment: I have added **self.line = mylineedit()** in MainWindow class.  and have change the **def mousePressEvent(self, event):** and under it **super().mousePressEvent(event)**. but its not working i don't know where i have done wrong?

Comment: @samannaz did you remove the `self.line = QLineEdit()`? Where did you put the `self.clicked.emit()`?

Comment: @musicamante after that line.

Comment: @samannaz `button_bulb_clicked` is invalid, as `self.line` has no `isChecked()` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QLineEdit, QApplication, QWidget



class main(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


        self.lineEdit = QLineEdit(self)
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Click Please")

        self.lineEdit.mousePressEvent = self.clickLine

        self.resize(200,100)
        self.show()  


    def clickLine(self, mouseEvent):
        self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("Thanks Man :)")


App = QApplication([])
window = main()
App.exec()
```

Comment: The OP already implemented the feature, the problem was because they didn't use the right class, so it was just a typo. Note that overwriting event handlers like this is discouraged, and should be done only if there is no other simpler (and safer) alternative, like subclassing or using event filters.

Comment: I know that too, it's not necessary to create a subclass, sometimes quick solutions may be required. Why are you obsessed with the rules?

Comment: @SimoNSavioR it just work fine for me

Comment: @SimoNSavioR rules are meant to be broken, but with awareness. When you want to break them, you accept their consequences; when you suggest breaking them, you should ensure that those consequences are known, or you should explain them.

Answer (score 0):

`QLineEdit` doesn't have `isChecked()` and `clicked` but you can use `QCheckBox()`

`self.line = QtWidgets.QCheckBox(self)`